# Minimum Samples to Identify Box (Coupon Collector Extension)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, sampling, coupon-collector

I am thinking on the follow probabilistic problem setting:

Say we have $n$ boxes, each of which has an affiliated set of $k$ balls. We aim to distribute these balls across the boxes in the most fair manner (each receiving an equal number of balls). The contributed balls are broken down as follows:

1. The first $n-1$ boxes each contribute $k$ balls which can only be given to themselves (call them ''specific'' to these boxes). As such, these $(n-1)k$ balls have no ambiguity as to where they can be distributed.
2. For the final box, we have $k$ balls which each have a probability equal to $1/2$ of being "specific" to that box or non-specific (can be put in any box).

If we are given all the balls at once (an ''offline'' setting), we can trivially distribute so that each box has $k$ balls.

My question is this, somewhat a coupon collector problem:

If the balls are arriving one-by-one (randomly), how many do we have to see before we can identify which box is the unique "final" box (or with high probability make this conclusion)? I have analyzed this for the setting where the final box instead contributes *only* non-specific items (or the probability of being specific is $p=0$), which is almost exactly a coupon collector problem (once we have seen one of each specific item, we know the box that is not specific). However, for the more complex case that the special box has *some* specific items, it seems that we would need to sample more to identify this box?

**EDIT:** It is also important to note that when $k=\infty$ we are much closer to a coupon collector instance. Additionally, with $k=1$ the problem is trivial so we are assuming $k$ is large in some sense.

Comment: If we see an item, do we know whether it's specific? (If not, how do we know which is the final box once we've seen one of each specific item?)

Comment: @joriki yes, sorry. When the ball is observed we are given the information as to where it can be placed, ie. either in exactly one of the bins or in any bin.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. If you want to identify the final box with certainty, clearly you can't, since it might produce only specific balls like all the others. If you want what you wrote in parentheses ("or with high probability make this conclusion"), what exactly are you looking for? The expected number of balls until the posterior distribution for identifying the final box (presumably given a uniform prior) reaches some probability threshold? Or its peak as a function of the number of balls?

Comment: @joriki the peak as a number of balls is what I am thinking. Sorry if it ill posed, I have made this construction in working towards a hardness result. My hope is that I can make some argument that we need the input system to be large enough to have a hope at identifying the one unique box (thus, after this point, we know all non-specific items should be put in this box to maintain fairness for the remainder of the sequence).

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a complicated problem, but a rough estimate is available for $k=\infty$. In that case, we expect to need $n\log n+(m-1)n\log\log n+O(n)$ balls to have at least $m$ specific balls in each normal box (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Extensions_and_generalizations)). The expected number of specific balls in the final box at this point is

$$\frac1{2n}\left(n\log n+(m-1)n\log\log n+O(n)\right)=\frac12\left(\log n+(m-1)\log\log n\right)+O(1)\;.$$

For this to be less than $m$, we need
$$\frac12\left(\log n+(m-1)\log\log n\right)\lt m$$

$$\rightarrow m\gt\frac{\log n-\log\log n}{2-\log\log n}\;.$$

This diverges for $\log\log n=2$, that is, for $n=\mathrm e^{\mathrm e^2}\approx1618$. Beyond that point, the number of specific balls in the final box grows faster than the minimal number of specific balls in the normal boxes, so you can never hope to reliably identify the final box.

If $k$ is finite, you need to see an appreciable proportion of the $kn$ balls until it becomes sufficiently likely for the underpopulated boxes to be filled.